# JavaFX Candlestick Chart Background Separators

Tags: java, javafx

How do I get rid of the alternating light gray and white horizontal separator strips in the background?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [styling charts with CSS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm), explicitly "Example 8-6 Setting a Transparent Background for the Chart Plot".

```
.chart-plot-background {
  -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.chart-alternative-row-fill {
  -fx-fill: transparent;
  -fx-stroke: transparent;
  -fx-stroke-width: 0;
}
```

Also:

> You can make the alternative rows invisible by applying the setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false) method to the chart in the JavaFX application.